# Creating Multiple AWS EBS volumes and attach it to an instance using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ebs

I am creating a terraform configuration to allow user to input the number of AWS EBS volumes they want to attach to the EC2 instance.

```
variable "number_of_ebs" {}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs_att" {
  count = "${var.number_of_ebs}"
  device_name= "/dev/sdh"
  volume_id   = "${element(aws_ebs_volume.newVolume.*.id, count.index)}"
  instance_id = "${aws_instance.web.id}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-14c5486b"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  vpc_security_group_ids=["${aws_security_group.instance.id}"]
  key_name="KeyPairVirginia"
  tags {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "newVolume" {
  count = "${var.number_of_ebs}"
  name  = "${format("vol-%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
  size              = 4
  type="standard"
  tags {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

It surely is giving error. I am unaware of how to dynamically assign different name to each volume that is created and get volume_id to the attach to the instance.

Below is the error that I get.

```
  var.number_of_ebs
  Enter a value: 2

  Error: aws_ebs_volume.newVolume[0]: : invalid or unknown key: name

  Error: aws_ebs_volume.newVolume[1]: : invalid or unknown key: name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ebs_volume.html) for resource `aws_ebs_volume`, you see that the argument `name` is not supported.
This explains the error message.